# Waiting for root device PARTUUID=e91c4e10-16e6-4c0e-bd0e-77becf4a3582... problem on stm32mp157

Tags: stm32, yocto

I have problems with loading yocto-image on sd-card on STM32MP157. Loading stucks at this point.

[    3.343164] Waiting for root device PARTUUID=e91c4e10-16e6-4c0e-bd0e-77becf4a3582...

[    3.591162] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-platform

[    3.793178] hub 2-1:1.0: USB hub found

[    3.795772] hub 2-1:1.0: 4 ports detected

[   33.751270] usb33: supplied by vdd_usb

[   33.753835] vref: supplied by vdd

[   33.757086] vref: disabling

[   33.759675] vdda: disabling

I search some information and change path in extlinux.conf file but it didn't work for me. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Welcome to SO! First, [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Second, I'm not *entirely* sure if this fits on SO, as it doesn't seem to be directly programming related.